# is there a function in Excel to apply the below logic

Tags: excel, regex, function, if-statement

if the column value is 1, I need to print 1.0000 and

if the column value is 1.1 , i need to print 1.0001

if  1.10 -> 1.0010

if 1.100 -> 1.0100

I am trying to think with regex, is there a way to code like this in excel?

if column has ([0-9].[0-9]{1}) -> add 3 zeros after decimal

if column has ([0-9].[0-9]{3}) -> add 1 zero after decimal

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean to print from an Excel function?

Comment: Please clarify the problem: are you just looking for these specific values, or any number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide enough details about your problem, but I tried to solve it as I understood it.
Firstly, you have to store your inputs as TEXT since 1.1 is equal to 1.10, 1.100, 1.1000
Then you can use the following formula to get the required outputs

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=3,CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,2),"000",RIGHT(A1,1)),
IF(LEN(A1)=4,CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,2),"00",RIGHT(A1,2)),
IF(LEN(A1)=5,CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,2),"0",RIGHT(A1,3)),
IF(LEN(A1)=6,CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,2),"",RIGHT(A1,4)),""))))
```

[image]

Comment: Another simple solution is the using of VLOOKUP function, but this will work only if you are using fixed input values i.e. 1.1,1.10,1.100, 1.1000

Comment: I suspect OP wants something a bit more general, so that `123.10` would yield `123.0010`, but they didn't specify their problem very clearly. My approach would be to split on the period, keep the left part as is, and left-pad the right part with zeros, but I have no idea how to do this in Excel...